# Dynamically resizing an embeded video with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, flash, video, embed

I've tried a few ways but nothing seems to work.  What I'd like to do is have my users post video's with the given embed code (example):

```
<object id="cnbcplayer" classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" width="400" height="380" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,40,0">
 <param name="type" value="application/x-shockwave-flash" />
 <param name="allowfullscreen" value="true" />
 <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />
 <param name="quality" value="best" />
 <param name="scale" value="noscale" />
 <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
 <param name="bgcolor" value="#000000" />
 <param name="salign" value="lt" />
 <param name="src" value="http://plus.cnbc.com/rssvideosearch/action/player/id/1398301408/code/cnbcplayershare" />
 <param name="name" value="cnbcplayer" />
 <embed id="cnbcplayer" 
        type="application/x-shockwave-flash" 
        width="400" 
        height="380" 
        src="http://plus.cnbc.com/rssvideosearch/action/player/id/1398301408/code/cnbcplayershare" 
        name="cnbcplayer" 
        salign="lt" 
        bgcolor="#000000" 
        wmode="transparent" 
        scale="noscale" quality="best" 
        allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true">  
 </embed>
```

But then, I want to resize it to be 300px wide.  I've tried updating the attributes with jQuery but that didn't work.  Any ideas on what could solve this?

Thanks

Comment: Could you reformat the code to multiple lines, please? It's a bit hard to read this.

Comment: Reformatted - still a basic flash movie embed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to place `object` with `width: "100%"` into a `div` and resize that div container.

Comment: This will work but makes the video width 100% always.  I'm using this as a sidebar to a blog, so I would like to keep the correct aspect ratio in the post but preview the most recent videos on the homepage sidebar.

I've tried using jQuery to update the attributes but it doesn't seem to work:

jQuery('#sideVideo').closest('object').attr('width','100%');

I am missing something on the jQuery side but am not sure what.

Comment: Darmen - while this worked it was actually jQuery related - I guess I can't use "closest" and instead had to specify the child object I was trying to modify.

Comment: Hmm... try `Query('#sideVideo').closest('object').parent("#yourDiv").attr('width','500px');` and specify `width: "100%"` to `object`.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this function:

```
/**
 * resize_embedded resizes embedded videos like youtube videos;
 * Examples: 
 *  - resize_embedded($('youtube_div'), 300, 200);
 *  - Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xjxVC/1
 *
 * Parameters:
 * @param jquery the element that contains the embedded media
 * @param number the new width
 * @param number the new height
 *
 */
function resize_embedded(){

    // Did we receive 3 correct parameters
    if(arguments.length === 3 && $(arguments[0]).length && isNumber(arguments[1]) && isNumber(arguments[2])) 
        ;
    else
        return 0;

    // Clone embedded element
    $c = $(arguments[0]).clone();

    // Resize clone (replace width/height of all children who have them) 
    $c
        .attr('width', arguments[1])
        .attr('height', arguments[2])
        .children().each(function(){     
            $(this).attr('width') && $(this).attr('width', arguments[1]);
            $(this).attr('height') && $(this).attr('height', arguments[2]);
    })

    // Replace target with clone
    $(arguments[0]).replaceWith($c);
}

function isNumber(n){
    return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xjxVC/1

Comment: If the video is playing, your function will restart it. Not something that a user would expect.